# Count number of bytes written to QDataStream in Qt5

Tags: c++, count, qt5, qdatastream

In my code I am preparing some data for sending over a network using `QDataStream`. In the middle of the preparations I would like to know exactly how many bytes that were prepared at that point. How can I do that?

Example:

```
int myFunc(QDataStream &ds){
   ds << "hello"
   ds << 123;
   ds << 456.7f;
   //...
   //How can I do this:
   return ds.numberOfBytesPipedIntoThisQDataStreamAtThisTime();
}
```

Comment: What you mean by "preparing"? Are you streaming data to some buffer in memory and once all data is ready, send it over network?

Comment: Yes. My QDataStream wraps a QByteArray that is later sent over the wire.

Answer (score 2):

This could work (although it looks not very elegant).

```
int myFunc(QDataStream& ds){
    QBuffer buf;
    buf.open(QBuffer::WriteOnly);
    QDataStream tmpStream(&buf);

    tmpStream << "hello";
    tmpStream << 123;
    tmpStream << 456.7f;
    int written = buf.size();
    if(ds.device()->write(buf.data()) != buf.data().size()) {
        // handle error
    }
    return written;
}
```

Comment: `ds << buf.data();` - this code will writes **4 bytes** + data - https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/datastreamformat.html

Comment: Is there any reason why I would prefer QBuffer over say QByteArray?

Comment: @LennartRolland No. `QBuffer` uses `QByteArray` as storage, so they are similar.

Answer (score 2):

Usual way to know the number of bytes:

```
QByteArray buf;
QDataStream stream( &buf, QIODevice::ReadWrite );
stream << someData;
int count = buf.size();
```

Comment: This is actually what I am doing now.